# Exclude dependencies from Gradle file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management, gradle-dependencies

I have a dependency which exist in two places - one is in GitHub and another one is in internal Maven repository. While doing internal testing, I do testing from the Maven internal repository, and when doing release testing, I should get artifact only from GitHub and exclude the artifact downloading from internal Maven repository. I don't want to comment the Maven internal repository while doing release testing. How can I exclude a dependency downloading from the internal Maven repository.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url "https://github.com.sample.repo.url"

            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
                name = "Authorization"
                value = "Bearer " + "${findProperty('githubtoken')}"
            }
            authentication {
                header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://anotherurl.com"
            credentials {
                username "VSTS"
                password System.getenv("VSTS_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN") ?: "${findProperty('vstsGradleAccessToken')}"
            }
            content {
                exclude group: 'somegroupname', module: 'somemodulename'
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you could make the exclusion dependent on some property, but you should first consider if you can use something like [Maven repository filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#maven_repository_filtering), e.g. assuming your test dependencies use SNAPSHOT in the version declaration.